# CollectionView data not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uicollectionview

I am sending the data to collection view but I am getting the error `[__NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.` Please help me. Thank you.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];
    //    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    //    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    //    thumbnailImgView.image = image;


    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"One-Album.png"]];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are populating `recipeImages`?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    recipeImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img.png", @"One-Album.png", @"Create-Album.png", @"AllPhotos.png", @"Albums.png", @"brightness1.png", @"original1 (1).png", @"crop1.png", nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [recipeImages count];
}

Comment: i am getting error at this line.  recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: Try this:
`[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: Please check `recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` recipeImage specifically if you adding actual Array of Array value not Array of String.

Comment: i am getting the same erroe

Comment: recipeImages is an array of array?

Comment: do an nslog recipeImages[indexPath.section] before setting recipeImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to be wrong `[recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

If `recipeImages` is a type of `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, you should use `[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` .

**Example:**

```
if([recipeImages count] > indexPath.row)
{
   recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Unable to get the image name");
}
```

Comment: -[CustomCell setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance this is the error i am getting with this code

Comment: did you add the check? if([recipeImages count] > indexPath.row) , see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are trying to treat an `NSString` as an `NSArray`! When you said, 
`recipeImages[indexPath.section]`, it will return you a string type. Now if you are trying to do, `objectAtIndex` on a String type, it will crash.

`[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` should solve your issue.